# How to send HTML mail in PHP with BOOTSTRAP formatting

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, phpmailer

What's the best way to construct and send an HTML email using `mail()`with bootstrap formatting?
I've tried the following example (not full code):

```
$msg = "
<html>
<head>
<link href = '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a request to reset your password</p>
<a href='blah'>Click here to reset your password.</a>
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-info btn-sm'>Reset</button>
</body>
</html>
";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"."\r\n"; "X-Mailer: php".
$headers .= 'From: Password Reset <passwordreset@blah.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
```

The mail sends and is received in html but not formatted.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at [Zurb's Foundation for emails](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html) project. It's much lighter than bootstrap and is designed to work with inliners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you put all of the bootstrap code directly in your email, no. Email clients remove remote files by default to prevent user tracking. You cannot code around this.

Comment: That's what I thought - so basically I would have to inline-style every element using Bootstrap's CSS?

Comment: If you really wanted to use it? Yes. But I would think it would be easier to just use your own custom styles that are need for that email only.

Comment: You can use an inliner to do that for you, much easier than trying to do it by hand.